# Returning Results from different tables depending on conditions from two other tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 4 tables (table1-table4) containing names and values associated with those names like this:

table1

```
ID  Name_1  Name_2

1   Jeff    Jeff

2   Nancy   Jasmine
```

table2

```
ID  Name_1  Name_2

3   Jeff    Jeff

4   Nancy   Nancy
```

table3

```
Name  Value

Jeff   5.5

Nancy  6.5
```

table4

```
Name  Value

Jeff  7.5

Nancy 8.5
```

I need to get the ID# from table1 and the value from tables 3 OR 4 depending on how the names are arranged between tables 1 and 2 (there will be other tables to get a return Value from but right now Im just trying to nail down 2).

Example….In the tables above Jeff appears twice in table 1 and twice in table 2 so I want to return ID#1 from table1 with a value of 5.5 from table3 while Nancy appears once in table1 and twice in table2, so I want to return ID#2 from table1 and a value of 8.5 from table4.  Altogether like this:

```
ID  Value

1   5.5  (based on the sharing between table1 and table 2 return value from table 3)

2   8.5 (based on the sharing between table1 and table 2 return value from table 4)
```

I have:

```
SELECT dbo.table1.ID
    CASE
    WHEN((dbo.table2.Name_1)=(dbo.table2.Name_2) AND
        (dbo.table1.Name_1)=(dbo.table1.Name_2) AND
        (dbo.table2.Name_1)=(dbo.table1.Name_1) AND
        (dbo.table2.Name_2)=(dbo.table1.Name_2) AND
        (dbo.table2.Name_1)=(dbo.table1.Name_2) AND
        (dbo.table2.Name_2)=(dbo.table2.Name_1)) THEN (SELECT dbo.table3.Value FROM dbo.table3 WHERE dbo.table3.Name = dbo.table2.Name_1)
    ELSE Null
    END AS Value
FROM dbo.table1, dbo.table3
INNER JOIN dbo.table2 ON dbo.table3.Name = dbo.table2.Name_1
```

What is returned is this:

```
ID#  Value

1    5.5

2    NULL
```

There are even more ways of sharing the names between tables 1 and 2 and I need the values returned from the respective tables depending on the sharing.

If I wanted to return Nancy, I would write the above query like this:

```
SELECT dbo.table1.ID
    CASE
    WHEN((dbo.table2.Name_1)=(dbo.table2.Name_2) AND
        (dbo.table1.Name_1)<>(dbo.table1.Name_2) AND
        (dbo.table2.Name_1)=(dbo.table1.Name_1) AND
        (dbo.table2.Name_2)<>(dbo.table1.Name_2) AND
        (dbo.table2.Name_1)<>(dbo.table1.Name_2) AND
        (dbo.table2.Name_2)=(dbo.table2.Name_1)) THEN (SELECT dbo.table4.Value FROM dbo.table4 WHERE dbo.table4.Name = dbo.table2.Name_1)
    ELSE Null
    END AS Value
FROM dbo.table1, dbo.table4
INNER JOIN dbo.table2 ON dbo.table4.Name = dbo.table2.Name_1
```

I get:

```
ID#  Value

1    NULL

2    8.5
```

For the life of me, I can’t figure out how to combine them into a single result like this:

```
ID#  Value

1    5.5

2    8.5
```

Anyone got any ideas on how I might be able to do this or what adjustments I can make to what I have to do this?  I first tried adding multiple cases but because I needed to select from and join more than two tables it just wouldn’t work (or at least I don’t know quite how to do it).

Comment: This is an odd design to say the least. Why do you have duplicated tables in your database?

Comment: It might be difficult to help you unless you can explain what exactly the criteria are for whether you're pulling from table1 or table2. You say things like `depending on the sharing`. Can you explain what exactly the `depending` means?

Comment: Sorry.  I’ll try to clarify a little better.  Tables 3 and 4 are indices of values calculated based on different formulas (there will be three more tables but I was just trying to get two to work before incorporating more tables).  If names 1 and 2 are all the same across tables 1 and 2, pull the value from table 3.  If three are the same across tables 1 and 2, pull from table 4.  If two match across tables 1 and 2, pull from table 5.  If name1 and name2 don’t match each other but both match across table 1 and 2 pull from table 6.  If none match across tables 1 and 2 pull from table 7.

Comment: Now....each set of names belongs to a category.  So Cat1Name_1, Cat1Name_2, Cat2Name_1, Cat2Name_2....up to Cat25_2.  There will be 50 name fields paired for comparisons across tables 1 and 2.  All Cat1Names will be compared to cat1names to return a Cat1 value.  I’ve only shown 1 category in my original question to keep things as simple as possible.

Comment: ...and tables 1 and 2 aren’t duplicated.  They’re similar types of information but must be in different tables but compared.

Comment: There was an answer here that I tested and it worked out pretty well...I wanted to upvote and mark as solved on that answer to give that person credit but I can’t....