# SELECT INTO returning multiple records when it should return 1

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

*EDIT:
I've since edited the query using JOINS instead of a WHERE clause in light 
of suggested comments. I was using a WHERE clause instead of JOIN because I 
couldn't get it to work across three tables but have figured it out.  I've
also inserted SELECT DISTINCT because it does solve the problem.
Thanks @MichaelEvanchik, and @SeanLange for the help.  Im still learning and hope I don't frustrate you guys too much.*

I've looked over many of the multiple return threads and don't seem to find an answer that helps me.

I have 4 tables.

table1

```
ID    Cat1_Name1    Cat1_Name2    Cat2_Name1    Cat2_Name2

12      Mike          Mike         George         Mike

13      Jen           Jen           Amy           Amy

14      Jeff          Jen           Mike          Ben

15      Jeff          Jeff          Fred          Tom

16      George        Jen           Luke          Amy
```

table2

```
ID    Cat1_Name1    Cat1_Name2    Cat2_Name1    Cat2_Name2

25      Mike          Mike          Jen           George
```

table3

```
Name    Cat1_Value    Cat2_Value

Mike       6.5          20.25

Jen       10.2           0.5

Jeff      11.5           1.5

George    8.0            27.1
```

table4

```
Name     Cat1_Value    Cat2_Value

Mike       7.8           20.0

Jen        6.0           13.0

Jeff       13.2          5.0

George     8.0           1.2
```

Before anyone asks, the set of names in table2 must stay separate from table1.  It isn’t duplicate information, but a SINGLE UNKNOWN SET that will be compared to every record in table1, which can contain millions of known sets (i.e.; no ID’s in table1 will ever match the ID in table2). If you look at the tables you can see that the set of names CAN match between table1 and table2 but do not have to.  For example, the names for cat1 match between tables 1 and 2 for ID 12 and 25 (all 4 are Mike) but doesn't match any between IDs 13,14,15,16 and 25 (only the two in 25 are Mike). While at cat2, ID 12 and 25 match partially (i.e., the names in cat2 between tables 1 and 2 contain the name George but do not match in the second name).  Here I show two categories.  There will be upwards of 30 categories of names for one record but for now, I am focusing on 1 to solve this particular problem.  Cat1_Name1, Cat1_Name2.  I will worry about aggregating the different categories and logical name combinations with JOINs and UNIONs and answer my other question later….hopefully.

I want to create a new table that returns the ID from table1, with the associated value for each category depending on how many names match in the category. For example, since cat1_name 1 and 2 in table1 are mike,mike AND cat1_name 1 and 2 in table2 are mike,mike, return the ID from table 1 (12)  and value in table 3 for cat1 (6.5).  Different sets of matching names would return values from different tables (i.e.; the partially matching set in cat2 between 12 and 25 might return the value from table4 etc).  I asked a similar question about this previously, here but the problem was different:

[Returning Results from different tables depending on conditions from two other tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50241172/returning-results-from-different-tables-depending-on-conditions-from-two-other-t?noredirect=1#comment87500294_50241172)

I have a partial answer for it but now have a different problem.  I plan on posting an answer to the first, once I figure out this problem (hopefully with a little help  ).

Here’s my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT dbo.table1.ID, dbo.table3.Cat1_Value
INTO Cat1Table
FROM dbo.table2
INNER JOIN dbo.table3 ON (dbo.table1.Cat1_Name1 = dbo.table3.Name ) AND
                         (dbo.table1.Cat1_Name2 = dbo.table3.Name )
INNER JOIN dbo.table1 ON (dbo.table2.Cat2_Name1 = dbo.table3.Name ) AND
                         (dbo.table2.Cat2_Name2 = dbo.table3.Name )
```

Result table that I want:

Cat1Table

```
ID    Cat1_Value

12       6.5
```

What I’m getting:

Cat1Table

```
ID    Cat1_Value

12       6.5

12       6.5
```

Why am I getting a duplicate?  Is it my logic or am I missing something else more simple?  If I use SELECT DISTINCT it gives me the correct return but I'm thinking there might be a more efficient way because this will be expanded to millions of records.  Wouldn't SELECT DISTINCT slow everything down?

Comment: 12      Mike          Mike
is your issue, mike is in table 1 twice.  Distinct will slow things down if its allot of data.

Comment: you need INNER JOIN

Comment: its also in table 2 twice

Comment: I would start with using ANSI-92 style joins. They have been around now for more than 25 years. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins And I question your tables. Things like cat1_value, cat2_value are a huge red flag that your tables suffer for a lack of normalization.

Comment: i agree your joins are defaulting to an old style.  which i believe is an inner join though

Comment: @MichaelEvanchik those are implicit cross joins which are then logically turned into inner joins with the where predicates. Yes it works but...

Comment: either way @Dan your all of your "joins" qualify for one record, twice

Comment: Here’s the thing.  Those sets of names MUST be paired and can pair with themselves.  So having mike mike as a possible pair, has to stay.  Mike could also be paired with Jen or Stacy or whoever.  As far as normalization goes, the values are pre calculated numbers based on the possible pairing.  All possible values are set and indexed.  Calculating them on the fly slows things down even further...which is the point of indexing, isn’t it?

Comment: @MichaelEvanchik Then Is there a way to stop this?

Comment: What would really help here is you could post that data in a consumable format. IE, create table statements followed by insert statements. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ But my question is that if you want only distinct values why not use distinct in the query?

Comment: @SeanLange I’m just under the impression that doing that is going to slow this down considerably when the number of records got significantly larger?

Comment: Don't do anything when "under the impression" that something might happen. Test it and be certain. How do you expect to get distinct values from a query that returns duplicates? You have two options, use distinct or use group by.

Comment: if you have indexes (which you still havent shown) use group by, otherwise optimizer and distinct is just fine.  but again i have no idea if mike, and mike, are the same mike

Comment: They are two different mikes but they have the same exact name and the only thing that matters is that they match.  You could also think of them as each being a jack of spades from two different decks of cards.  As far as getting the indices of the values, I’m happy with how I got there and again, calculating the values on the fly is more work and more taxing than having them all pre calculated...kind of like a data mart.

Comment: @Dan if your saying that mike and mike could/or are two different people , and table 3 mike, is only 1 of those mikes data.  This cant be correct.  You might want to use sqlfiddle.com if you would like more help and answers to things like  what is the purpose of table4? and the other mike fact i just said

Comment: Sigh....there are other situations for matching.  There are different sets of values from different tables for others situations.  I’m only asking about one because of the duplicates but showing that others are possible.  Table four would be used for a different set of matching that at this point doesn’t matter.  As far as the mike, mike issue all that matters is that they match....I guess I should have stuck with two decks of cards but I figured names would be easier to follow.  They’re different but look exactly the same.  They match. No more, no less.  Distinct/Group by it is.  Thanks!

Comment: @Dan ok no problem, glad you helped